# Typescript error because of props in conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is this simple conditional statement with component return:

```
let content = movies.length > 0 ? movies.map((movie, i) => <MovieCard key={i} movie={movie} />) : null;
```

Typescript shows error on 'movie' prop:

```
TS2322: Type '{ key: number; movie: object; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
        Property 'movie' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const MovieCard: React.FC = ({ movie }) => {

    return (
        <div className="col-md-3 mb-5">
            <div className="card card-body bg-dark text-center h-100">
                <img className="w-100 mb-2" src={movie.Poster} alt="Movie Cover" />
                <h5 className="text-light card-title">
                    {movie.Title} - {movie.Year}
                </h5>
                <Link className="btn btn-primary" to={'/movie/' + movie.imdbID}>
                    Movie Details
                    <i className="fas fa-chevron-right" />
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

Help to understand what did i miss, please. I'm new to TS.

Comment: Could you show code for how you defined your `<MovieCard />`

Comment: @haron68 There is nothing in it, actually

Comment: I think there might be issue with how you passed the prop movie into your react component. Are you sure it is proper in react to do `({movie}) => {...}`?

Comment: perhaps somehting like `(props) => {...}` and then you can use `movie` like `props.movie.Poster` or `props.movie.imdbID`.

Comment: @haron68 nope, i've tried that ‍♂️

Comment: What is the error message you got when you tried that?

Comment: @haron68 TS2339: Property 'movie' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define prop types for MovieCard functional component.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface Movie {
  imdbID: number,
  Title: string,
  Year: string
}

export interface Props {
   movie: Movie
}

const MovieCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ movie }) => {

    return (
        <div className="col-md-3 mb-5">
            <div className="card card-body bg-dark text-center h-100">
                <img className="w-100 mb-2" src={movie.Poster} alt="Movie Cover" />
                <h5 className="text-light card-title">
                    {movie.Title} - {movie.Year}
                </h5>
                <Link className="btn btn-primary" to={'/movie/' + movie.imdbID}>
                    Movie Details
                    <i className="fas fa-chevron-right" />
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MovieCard;
```

You can take a look into this [cheatsheet](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet) for react-typescript